# Will my own created files in another OctoberCms market plugin be removed on update?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I would like to change some files in marketplace plugin offline/mall/views/mail/_partials. Any update would make that change undone.  But I can add new files to the folder.
If the plugin would update to a newer version, would that delete my added files? Or does the update only take effect on the original plugin files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update would delete those files. There is pretty much always a way to dynamically extend the code to use your own templates without running the risk of losing your changes though, so if you ask a more specific question in the October Discord server we should be able to help you figure out how to do that.